# Docker Alpine Supervisor unix:///run/supervisord.sock no such file

Tags: docker, supervisord, alpine-linux

I use docker, docker-compose for images and created image based on alpine 3.10 with my applicaiton and supervisor (by documentation 3.3.5). But after I enterd in container and start supervisorctl I faced with error. Could someone help me how to resolve it ?

volumes from img

```
volumes:
    - ./php-consume/supervisord.conf:/etc/supervisord/conf.d/supervisord.conf
```

and my `supervisord.conf`

```
[program:messenger-consume]
command=php /var/www/symfony/bin/console messenger:consume success andraction_parse_row_success --limit=100
numprocs=2
autostart=true
autorestart=true
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d

[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
```

when I entered in container and run supervisorctl

```
ivan@ivan-laptop:~/hosts/docker-symfony$ docker exec -it bc6df01db4db ash
/var/www/symfony # supervisorctl 
unix:///run/supervisord.sock no such file
```

Comment: Can you include your `Dockerfile` in the question?  Trying to start and stop services inside a container is a little unusual and generally if you needed multiple things running, running them in separate containers is a better practice.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have supervisorctl section.
Be sure that you've copied supervisors conf file to /etc/suervisorsd.conf
***DockerFile***

```
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
```

or started it with param.

***DockerFile***

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```

Here is my typical configuration of ***supervisord.conf***

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/dev/shm/supervisor.sock
chmod=0700

[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory=supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///dev/shm/supervisor.sock
```

Comment: This helped me to use `supervisorctl status` command. Socket in /var/run/ don't accept connections in docker for me